# How to copy a data from QTextEdit widget without rewriting a data

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qtextedit

I am receiving a data from Serial port and display them on QTextEdit widget.
I am receiving a data constantly and I don't wanna stop it.

Initial screen (before):

[image: Initial screen (before)]

When I wanna copy the data I am getting such problem:

[image: The problem screen]

The program change cursor position to the position of the mouse click and appending a new data there.
For example:

data:

```
1.23;2.22;
1.33;3.32;
1.22;1.45;
```

I am trying to copy:

```
->(cursor)1.23;2.22;
1.33;3.32;
1.22;1.45;
```

So the program, set the cursor to the mouseclick position and starts rewrite a data:

```
2.22;3.33; (new data, that rewrote a previous line)
1.33;3.32;
1.22;1.45;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the text cursor to the end of the `QTextEdit` before inserting the new data:

```
QTextEdit *edit = ....;
QString newData = ...;

QTextCursor cursor = edit->textCursor();
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End); // Does not move the visual cursor
cursor.insertText(newData);
```

Note that the `moveOperation` does not change the visual cursor inside the `QTextEdit` only a (hidden) copy of the text cursor is moved. This is probably what you want in this case. Otherwise you should call `QTextEdit::setTextCursor` explicitly.